# Отключение стилей Boostrap в Navbar Yii2

Tags: yii2

Здравствуйте. 
Есть небольшая проблема: виджет Navbar использует классы Bootstrap, хотя я определил в конфигах свои. Из-за этого возникает проблема со стилями в шаблоне: 
Например:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как отключить использование Boostrap-классов? Либо как избежать данной проблемы?

```
    <?php
    NavBar::begin([
        'brandLabel' => false,
        'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
        'options' => [
            'class' => 'vertical-center'
        ]
    ]);
    echo Nav::widget([
        'options' => [
            'class' => 'vertical-center'
        ],
        'items' => [
            [
                'label' => 'Главная',
                'url' => [
                    '#'
                ],
                'options' => ['class' => 'hover-a'],
            ],
            [
                'label' => 'About',
                'url' => [
                    '#'
                ],
                'options' => ['class' => 'hover-a'],
            ],
            [
                'label' => 'Обратная связь',
                'url' => [
                    '#'
                ],
                'options' => ['class' => 'hover-a'],
            ],
            Yii::$app->user->isGuest ? [
                'label' => 'Войти',
                'url' => [
                    '#'
                ]
            ] : [
                'label' => 'Выйти ('.Yii::$app->user->identity->username.')',
                'url' => [
                    '#'
                ],
                'linkOptions' => [
                    'data-method' => 'post'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]);
    NavBar::end();
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй в своих стилях прописать !important

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Ну это поможет при наличии этих стилей, т.е. нужно будет создавать стили, которые оставлять пустыми и переопределять их.